# Are e-mail accounts on Android available to every program?

Tags: android, synchronization, accounts

I am not familiar with Android accounts API and am worried about accounts security.
Also I believe that programmers know more about Android insides so am asking this question here.

Android device can have several accounts of various types stored: Google, Skype, Email ...

So I have several questions:

- Can any application with `ACCOUNT_MANAGER`, `AUTHENTICATE_ACCOUNTS` etc. rights read these accounts' parameters and probably reconfigure them?
- Why do many applications store accounts centralized but not separately, in their own data storage?
- Does Google know about all these accounts on my phone?

Answer (score 2):

These links might give you better idea about how permissions and accessibility work:
http://lifehacker.com/5991099/why-does-this-android-app-need-so-many-permissions
and this
http://www.theregister.co.uk/2013/08/06/android_oneclick_authentication_open_to_hacking/

Answer (score 1):

```
 - Can any application with ACCOUNT_MANAGER, AUTHENTICATE_ACCOUNTS etc.
 rights read these accounts' parameters and probably reconfigure them?
```

Short answer, no. If the app has `MANAGE_ACCOUNTS` can access **only** to the account created by that app, also can modify it. `AUTHENTICATE_ACCOUNTS` permission is used to use specific account as part of authentication processes, such as using Google account for login for your app. `ACCOUNT_MANAGER` is used to store your account in the account authenticators, documentation says that it is used by the system to deal with the existing and new accounts not the third party apps.

```
 - Does Google know about all these accounts on my phone?
```

Maybe not. Maybe if someone has digged more info, if Google digs info from your phone about your accounts can give more precise answer.